# Redirecting to error page within ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

I am using jQuery's ajax functions to make my ajax request.

My question is if I caught an error how do I then redirect to a error page, say I've got the error, logged it, and now want to redirect to a error page, is it possible within the ajax request or will it just redirect the request not the page performing the request?

Do I have to state an error has occurred within the request, by changing the headers HTTP status to say 500 then within the ajax error function direct to a error page?

However within my ajax request if I have already echoed out data and then want to change the header information, will cleaning the buffer allow me to then change the headers?

Is this how I would clean the buffer?

`if(ob_get_length()) ob_clean();`

How I normally redirect, include a error page :

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
readfile("500.html");
```

Within my ajax request would I just change the header like above and then deal with the rest with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its up to you how you want to handle it, you could return a 500, or you could always return a 200 and a status message.

You will have to change page from inside javascript though, in response to your ajax call,

you can do this using [location property of window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)

`window.location = '/yourlocation'`

another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call) about redirecting in response to an ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect using javascript , after ajax call , on error :

```
error: function () {

    // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
    window.location.replace("http://mysite.com/500.html");

  }
```